# Cut to the quick part

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, history

> Bill the grave offender,
>   venerable, form filler,
>   leaving a paper trail,
>   found on an old 3D tail,
>   the fastest ending last,
>   bucks the trend on April first?

Comment: What are we supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> HARE.

*Bill the grave offender,*

> This refers to William (Bill) Hare, one of the infamous Burke & Hare duo of criminals. "Grave" has a double meaning here, since IIRC they were grave robbers.

*venerable, form filler,*

> [Apparently](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hare) the word "hare" can be used to mean "venerable", and a hare's home is called a "form". Thanks to @MOehm for help with this clue.

*leaving a paper trail,*

> In the outdoor game of Paper Chase, the designated "hare" leaves a paper trail to be followed by the "hounds".

*found on an old 3D tail,*

> A hare appears on the "tails" side of an [old 3d coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threepence_(Irish_coin)). Thanks @Tom (the OP) for help with this clue.

*the fastest ending last,*

> In the fable of the Hare and the Tortoise, the hare is faster but finishes last in the race.

*bucks the trend on April first?*

> Male hares are called "bucks", and the stereotypical mad March hare differs from humans in becoming *normal* on 1st of April.

Comment: @Tom Nice riddle! I enjoyed it. Would you believe that it was mostly the first (ambiguous) line that cracked it for me? :-D Re line 2: sorry, still don't get it. Re line 4: wow, that's obscure! Re line 6: thanks, added.

Comment: Funny how one thinks of 3d as three-dimensional nearly automatically. The linked wiktionary page says that hare is a regional form of venerable and that a form is the home of a hare, who is therefore a form filler.